# How can I make a function that interactively passes a time to run-at-time?

Tags: interactive, timers

I want to make a function that calls `run-at-time` while setting its repeat to nil. The only thing I want to be asked to supply is the duration after which run-at-time should call a function.

Evaluating the following does what I want except for interactively asking me to input the duration: `(run-at-time "120 min" nil 'my-custom-command)`

None of my attempts to turn this into an interactive function have succeeded.

I have tried the following:

```
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively 'run-at-time 'my-custom-command))
```

However, evaluating this causes me to be asked to input `run-at-time`'s repeat variable and the function to be called, neither of which I wish to supply. Putting 'nil' after 'run-at-time' to bypass the request for the repeat interval returns a "too many arguments" error message.

I have experimented within the forms of `run-at-time` (run-at-time TIME REPEAT FUNCTION &rest ARGS) and `call-interactively`  (call-interactively FUNCTION &optional RECORD-FLAG KEYS), but to no avail.

I have also tried using the "s" and "n" flags (perhaps incorrectly) in case they might allow a string or a number to supply run-at-time's duration, but though this results in a string or a number being asked for, supplying either returns an error message.

What would make this function work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t need or want `call-interactively`. You just want to supply enough information to `interactive` to prompt for a single value, and then call `run-at-time` with that value:

```lisp
(defun foo (time)
  (interactive "sRun at time: ")
  (run-at-time time nil 'my-custom-command))
```

Comment: Thank you very much; that works perfectly.

Comment: You’re welcome.